# Rails can not load bootstrap.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sprockets

I download bootstrap and put `bootstrap.css` and `bootstrap.js` into `my_app/vendor/assets/stylesheets` and `my_app/vendor/assets/javascripts` respectively and also edit these files as follow:

**app/assets/javascripts/application.js**

```
//= require bootstrap
```

**app/assets/stylesheets/application.css**

```
 *= require bootstrap
```

`bootstrap.css` is loaded properly but having problem to load `bootstrap.js`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And now you have a problem with loading the icons. I prefer to use the [bootstrap-sass gem](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass), where bootstrap is completely prepared for the asset pipeline, and sass, so I can even extend my own sass files with it.
That way also the glyphs are loaded correctly. But I prefer `font-awesome` for my glyphs, instead.

So in my `Gemfile` I write:

```
group :assets do
  gem 'bootstrap-sass'
  gem 'font-awesome-rails'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding bootstrap.js to

```
app/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js
```